# How to count number of id's in a sqlalchemy database using query.all()?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

```
class Artist(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    artist_name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    albums = db.relationship('Album',
                            backref='artist',
                            lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Artist '{}'>".format(self.artist_name)
```

**This is the test class**

```
def test_artists_count(self):
        c = Artist.query.all()
        self.assertEqual(2, c)
```

**This is the error that I am getting**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):enter code here
  File "/projects/challenge/myflaskproj/tests/test_models.py", line 65, in test_artists_count

self.assertEqual(2, c)

AssertionError: 2 != [<Artist 'Artist1'>, <Artist 'Artist2'>]
```

Comment: .all() is in test case and when i edit the test case to .count() the solution gets rejected by the platform

Answer (score 0):

you can check the number or rows of a query result by checking its length

the only line you need to change is this:

`self.assertEqual(2, len(c))`

Comment: Yeah tried that too. Test cases are successful. But after submission it is rejecting that answer

Comment: What do you mean "after submission"? Is the database you are testing on locally the same database the tests run against after "submission". If not then there could be a different number of artists in each database.